# Group Cells in TableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, cell

I know it's an easy issue, but I'm not able to group my cells in my tableview. I've changed the option to "Grouped" and it doesn't work.

Where can be the problem?

It's linked to File's Owner, has property, has IBOutlet, and it appears a normal TableView.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you take navigation based application and open RootViewController.xib and go to property and select style group under TableView attribute  and after that RootViewController.m file 
and run your app

```
// Customize the number of sections in the table view.
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 5;
}


// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 10;
}

-(void)setListTableView
{
    mytableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 59, 319, 358) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped]; 
    mytableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLineEtched;
    mytableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    mytableView.opaque = NO;
    mytableView.delegate = self;
    mytableView.dataSource = self;
    mytableView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    mytableView.scrollsToTop = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:mytableView];
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I'm programming a TableView in a new ViewController inside a NavigationController. That's why I say it doesn't work. I've done that in a new project and it works, it shows cells grouped. Why it doesn't work in my UITableViewController?? Thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: Ok, that's what I was looking for: 'initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped'